# MKDIR PHP & Header(location:)

Tags: javascript, php, html, header, mkdir

I have the following problem .. I have to ensure that initially I enter data in the table below and then after pressing the "submit" button I run the script createDirectory () and that I be redirected to the page contained in the header function. In addition to being redirected, you must also put in the page link the field "idCantiere"
..
With the attempts I've just made, once I press the button, it redirects me to the same page but all white.

Do you have any solutions to offer me?
I thought that with a simple header I could do the redirect ...

```html
<!doctype html>
<?php 

 $idCantiere = $_GET["idCantiere"];


 session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
     header('location: ../../../index.php');
    }
    else
    {
 
?>
<html>
<?php



?>

 
<head>
 <style>
  #senzaBordi{border-style: none;}
  
  .bordi{ 
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
  }
 </style>
    <link href="../bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Affidataria / Soci ATI</title>
 
</head>
<script>
 function color(el){
  if(el.value=="OK"){
    el.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="#00ff00";
  }
  else{
    el.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="#B35556";
  }
 }
 </script>
<body>



<?php
   
 function createDirectory()
  {
   $nomeCantiere = $_POST["nomeCantiere"];
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
   $date = date('Y-m-d');
   chdir("../../../../Archivio/Cantieri");    
   mkdir($date."_".$nomeCantiere);
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Done!');</script>";
   header('location:affidatario2.php?idCantiere=<?php echo $idCantiere?>');
  }
?>
   
<form method="POST" action="">
 <?php
     $idAffidataria = rand();
 ?>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="3px" id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" id="tab1" name="tab1" >
<?php
     if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>
 
  <tr>
    <td style=" border-style: none;" width="64"></td>
    <td width="1479" colspan="8" align="center" bgcolor="#a5dfff" style="border: 2px solid black;"><strong>AFFIDATARIA</strong></td>
    <td style=" border-style: none;" width="64"></td>
    <td width="1088" colspan="8" align="center" bgcolor="#B35556"><strong>R.I.    / C.S.E.</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=" border-style: none;"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"><strong>I.D.</strong></td>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CDECFD"><strong>Documento</strong></td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD"><strong>Note</strong></td>
 <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" ></td>
    <td style=" border-style: none;"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#B35556">Verifica</td>
    <td bgcolor="#B35556">Note sul doc</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=" border-style: none;"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">1</td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">Cantiere</td>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CDECFD"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="nomeCantiere" id="nomeCantiere" />&nbsp;</td>
 <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=" border-style: none;"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">1.1</td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">Ragione Sociale</td>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CDECFD"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="ragioneSociale" id="ragioneSociale"/>&nbsp;</td>
  <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" ></td>

 
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td style=" border-style: none;"></td>
 <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">1.2</td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">Tipologia Affidataria</td>
    <td  colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">
  
   <select name="tipologiaAffidataria" class="form-control chkEdit" enable>
     <option value="Affidataria" selected="selected">Affidataria</option>
     <option value="Mandataria">Mandataria</option>
     <option value="Mandante">Mandante</option>
     <option value="Esecutrice">Esecutrice</option>
    </select>
  
 </td>
   <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"style=" border-style: none;" ></td>
   <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"style=" border-style: none;" ></td>
   <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"style=" border-style: none;" ></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=" border-style: none;"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">2</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">Addetto sicurezza</td>
 <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"><input type="text" style="width: 220px;" class="form-control" name="addettoSicurezza" id="addettoSicurezza" value="<?php echo $savedAddettoSicurezza; ?>"/></td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD">Mail</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"><input type="text" style="align:center;" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="mailAffidataria" id="mailAffidataria" value="<?php echo $savedMailAffidataria; ?>"/></td>

   <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Crea Directory Affidataria" href="affidatario2.php?idCantiere=<?php echo $idCantiere?>" class="btn btn-warning"></td>

</form>
  </tr>
  
<?php 
     }
     else{
       createDirectory();
    }
?>
</table>
 
 

 <script>
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
 <script language="javascript">
  function controlla(){
    x=document.prova;
    if (x.scelta.value=="si"){
      window.location.href = 'subAffidatario.php'
      return false;
    }
    if (x.scelta.value=="no"){
      alert("Hai risposto no");
       window.location.href = 'affidatario.php'
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
  <style>

    #drop_file_zone {

        background-color: #37bf00;

        border: #999 5px ;

        width: 150px;

        height: 150px;

        padding: 8px;

        font-size: 13px;
    }

    #drag_upload_file {

        width:50%;

        margin:0 auto;

    }

    #drag_upload_file p {

        text-align: center;

    }

    #drag_upload_file #selectfile {

        display: none;

    }
 
 .coloreTdDrop{
  background-color: #37bf00;
 }

</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var fileobj;
 function upload_file(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fileobj = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
 }

 function file_explorer() {
  document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
  document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function() {
      fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[0];
   ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
  };
 }

 function ajax_file_upload(file_obj) {
  if(file_obj != undefined) {
      var form_data = new FormData();                  
      form_data.append('file', file_obj);
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    success:function(response) {
     alert(response);
     $('#selectfile').val('');
    }
   });
  }
 }
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function protect(anObject, protection)
{
if (anObject == null) {
return true;
} // if (anObject == null)
var members = anObject.children.length;
var i = 0;
for (i=0;i<members;i++) 
{
 var curObject = anObject.children.item(i);
 if (curObject != null) 
 {
  protect(curObject,protection);
 } // if (curObject != null)
} // for (i=0;i<=members;i++)
anObject.disabled = protection;
return true;
} // function protect(anObject, protection)
//-->
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

[image: MyTable]

[image: Result of createDirectoryFunction]

Comment: Both the script and the HTML output are in serious need of getting un-messed … Try and follow the [IPO-Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model). And fix your HTML - f.e., you open the `form` first and then `table`, but then afterwards you close those elements in the order `/form`, `/tr`, `/table`.

Comment: And you open your form, then you have a `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` - and then you only _close_ the form inside that branch, but not in the else case. Again: Terrible mess, should IMHO be re-written from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

For starters your code for your header in the `createDirectory()` function has a problem:

`header('location:affidatario2.php?idCantiere=<?php echo $idCantiere?>');`

Should be:

`header('location:affidatario2.php?idCantiere=' . $idCantiere);`

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean but you really need to evaluate the flow of your code.  Start simple and add to it after you get the results that you want.  Try not to break in and out of php so much and your javascript should be loaded at the end of your page.

Comment: That would suggest that the `$_GET['idCantiere']` is not capturing the id from the url.  Check to make sure that that the id is in the url.

Comment: the id that I need is sure that it is placed in the URL, are you sure it is right to chain the string in this way?

Comment: Yes, that is how you would concatenate the string with the variable.  You need to echo out the `$idCantiere` as you go down your page to test that the variable contains the data that you want.

Comment: the site's first page is there once but I press the button that drives the header, although on the next page I do the $ _GET, it does not work ..

Comment: I just tried to put another field of the type name Construction and so it works ... helpp !!!

Comment: If you want me honest advise.  Start over.  Start small and make it work in small steps.  Take in all the advise that has been given to you on this page.  Best of luck! ~ Cheers

Comment: are you sure that the concatenation of a numerical occurs with the point?